# HIVE LOAD DATA INPATH

Tags: hadoop, hive

I tried to create a table in hive using the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE apple (dates STRING, open INT, high INT, low INT, close INT, adj_close DECIMAL, vol INT) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");**
```

Then I tried to load data using the command:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/root/stockdata/APPL.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE apple;
```

The file **APPL.csv** is stored in HDFS

Executing the above resulted in the following error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   Unable to load data to destination table. Error: The file that you are
>   trying to load does not match the file format of the destination
>   table. (state=42000,code=40000)

Can someone help resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Put the file directly into table location.

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /user/root/stockdata/APPL.csv' /user/<username>/apple
```

Substitute destination location with your table location. You can check it using `DESCRIBE FORMATTED tablename`.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data into the table in multiple ways!! But make sure that table format is valid.

- First put the specific table into the table location.

  > Syntax:  hadoop fs -put  source_path destination_hive_table_location
  >
  > Ex:    hadoop fs -put  APPL.csv /user/test.db/apple/APPL.csv
- Once file in Hadoop file system, we can load the file into the table via  load command in hive console

> load data inpath '/user/test.db/apple/APPL.csv' into table apple ;

PS: You are loading the CSV data.so make sure that the table has proper text input & output file format.

```
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this has to do with the creation of your table
I had the same error I resolved it by adding "STORED AS TEXTFILE" at the end of the hive query of the table creation

earlier my table was

```
    CREATE TABLE %(output_db)s.%(selected_query_tbl)s
    (
       query                     VARCHAR(255)
      ,ATC_beyond_10_percentage  DECIMAL(25,25)
      ,ATC_rate                  DECIMAL(25,25)
      ,block_5_tau               DECIMAL(25,25)
      ,Kendall_tau               DECIMAL(25,25)
    );
```

now it is

```
     CREATE TABLE %(output_db)s.%(selected_query_tbl)s
    (
       query                     VARCHAR(255)
      ,ATC_beyond_10_percentage  DECIMAL(25,25)
      ,ATC_rate                  DECIMAL(25,25)
      ,block_5_tau               DECIMAL(25,25)
      ,Kendall_tau               DECIMAL(25,25)
    )STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As Vipin soni said this is about the format of hive table we are saving it in.

```
Store as textfile;
```

solved this issue for me aswell